# character limit not work in two textarea on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two textarea and add [bootstrap max length](https://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/) limit character in second textarea like this:

```
$('input[maxlength], textarea#description').maxlength({
  alwaysShow: true,
  warningClass: "form-text text-muted mt-1", 
  limitReachedClass: "form-text text-muted mt-1",    
});
```

html:

```
<textarea id="summery" class="form-control my-5" placeholder="My textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="description" class="form-control my-5" placeholder="My textarea" maxlength="100"></textarea>
```

I link two textarea using `keyup` and get value from first textarea like this:

```
  $(function(){
      $('#summery').on('keyup', function(e){
          $('#description').val($(this).val());
      });
  });
```

Now, In action after type in first textarea I see this text in second area But bootstrap length character not working and not limited to second textarea. my mean is(I need): first textarea is unlimited character but second textarea is limited and stop character when I type in first textarea.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly0p2tox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can  solve it with if statement

```
 $(function(){
    $('#summery').on('keyup', function(e){
        if($('#summery').val().length<=$('#description').attr("maxlength")){
            $('#description').val($(this).val());
        }
        else{
            $('#description').val($(this).val().substring(0,$('#description').attr("maxlength")));
        }

    });
});
```